# Why might PlayEarcon error and how can I identify the actual reason?

Tags: android, xamarin, text-to-speech

I am attempting to intersperse sound effects with text in a Xamarin Android project, but I get an opaque error callback.

I first cache the earcon in a path given by

```
        var filename = Path.Combine(Application.Context.CacheDir.ToString(), id + ".wav");
```

(where `id` is unique to the earcon; the result on one emulator is `/data/data/My.Package/cache/fx1.wav`) and then call

```
        var result = _TTS.AddEarcon(id.ToString(), filename);
```

The result is `SUCCESS`.

Later I attempt to play it using

```
        var parms = new Android.OS.Bundle();
        // https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64925
        parms.PutInt(TextToSpeech.Engine.KeyParamStream, 3); // AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC
        parms.PutString(TextToSpeech.Engine.KeyParamUtteranceId, "earcon");
        var result = _TTS.PlayEarcon(id.ToString(), QueueMode.Add, parms, "earcon");
```

The result is a callback to `OnError(string)` on my registered `UtteranceProgressListener`.

I'm using API level 21, so I think it should call `OnError(string, TextToSpeechError)`; without the error code, I'm unsure what the problem is.

My best guess was that the audio format was unsupported, but this happens even with a mono 16000 Hz 16-bit stream, which [should be supported unconditionally](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html). The file plays back from the cached location via `MediaPlayer` without problems, and in fact my best workaround is to play a silent utterance of the right length and use the `UtteranceProgressListener` to trigger a `MediaPlayer` playing the file.

I observe the same problem on an emulated machine and on a real tablet.

What other causes for the error could there be? Is there any way to tell what the cause is other than guessing and trying a workaround?

Comment: Can you give me the `.wav` file to test?

Comment: @MikeMa, [base64-encoded](http://pastebin.com/raw/2zj7qtpq). I've created a quick test app in Android Studio and that works, so I'm starting to think it's a bug in Xamarin.